# How to turn android emulator?

Tags: android-emulator

Is it possible to rotate the android emulator with some short key ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> ctrl-f11

You can also use 7 or 9 on the keypad, but that works quirky sometimes on my system.

Comment: I tried `Ctrl+F11` and `Num_7` and `Num_9`, but it can't work. Then I did a bit of googling and I found that I need to turn off the `Num_Lock` first, then only press `Num_7` and `Num_9` for rotating.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

1) **7** or **9**

2) **ctrl+F11** or **ctrl+F12**

to turn android emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the another ctrl button and keep your num lock on computer keyboard is off.

Answer (score 0):

Press ctrl+F11 to rotate the emulator and do the same thing to rotate back to the default view.